# Plotting a graph for 2 elements in scilab within a For loop

Tags: plot, scilab

I am currently writing a program to show the relation between the Relaxation Factor and number of iterations it takes to achieve a solution using the [Successive OverRelaxation Method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SuccessiveOverrelaxationMethod.html)

This is the concerned For loop:

```
for (w = 0:0.05:2)
    T = -inv(D + w*L)*(w*U + (w -1) * D);
    C = inv(D + w*L) * w *B ;
    X = zeros(B);
   for(i = 1:1:MaxIter)
       X = T * X + C;
       err = A * X - B;
       if (abs(err) < abs(tol))
         break
    end
end 

disp("Relaxation Factor = " + string(w) +" No. of iterations = " + string(i));
```

I wish to draw a plot showing the relation between Relaxation factor and no. of iterations(between w and i). How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Just proceed as follow

```
  I=zeros(W)
  for k = 1:size(W,"*")
      w=W(k)
      T = -inv(D + w*L)*(w*U + (w -1) * D);
      C = inv(D + w*L) * w *B ;
      X = zeros(B);
     for(i = 1:1:MaxIter)
         X = T * X + C;
         err = A * X - B;
         if (abs(err) < abs(tol))
           I(k)=i
           break
         end
     end 
  end
  plot(W,I)
```

Comment: Thanks, however, 'W' is not defined in my code earlier. The relaxation factor is 'w'. Could you please elaborate on the logic used? I am a newbie to SciLab, by the way :)